# How can I fix this error when trying to plot a graph using plt.countourf in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, logistic-regression, matplotlib-basemap

*In this exercise on machine learning, I want  to plot a 2D graph using countourf function normaly included in matplotlib package. But I am getting the error massage: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'countourf'. I indcated it in my code below. I am using anaconda3 plateform and Jupyter 6.0.1, I am sure that this function exists in matplotlib (version 3.1.1), however, I do not know why this error occurs. Can anyone please, help me pass this stage and plot my dada? [Here is the link to find data:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xxo4xlsJkZ9w-V0kj8qCkbO-YbjR5w1a). Thank you in advance!*

```
`Importing the Librairies`
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
%matplotlib inline 

`Importing  the data`
SUV_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Wolf/Documents/ExoData/Data Science Tutorial/archive/SocialNetworkAds.csv")
SUV_data

`Extratcting only the dependant variables`
x = SUV_data.iloc[:, [2,3]].values

`Extratcting only the independant variables`
y = SUV_data.iloc[:, 4].values

print("x_dependent variables = " +str(x))
print("y_independent variables = " +str(y))

x.shape, y.shape
((400, 2), (400,))

`Plotting of a map showing how the dependent and independant variables are correlated with each other(facultative)`
YES_map = sb.heatmap(SUV_data.corr())

`Splitting the data into training and set models`
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

X_train.shape, y_train.shape
((300, 2), (300,))

`Fitting logistic regression to training data`
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state =0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

`Predicting the test set esults`
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred

`Visualize the Training set Results`
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.5), np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() -1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.5))
plt.countourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape), alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.mmin(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1], c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-7bff781bd170> in <module>
      3 X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
      4 X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.5), np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() -1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.5))
----> 5 ax = plt.countourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape), alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
      6 plt.xlim(X1.mmin(), X1.max())
      7 plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'countourf'

`Here is where the error occurs. How to fix it using countorf function or other in matplotlib?`
```

Comment: In the mean time, I will uninstall then reinstall matplotlib to see if I can obtain a better outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the "contourf" instead of the "countourf" function.

Here is a link to the documentation of the "contourf" function:

> https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html

The matplotlib library doesn’t has a "countourf" function at all.

I hope that helped.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much! I did not even see it at all! Now something shows up! Damn! Thanks for this remark, it's okay now!

Comment: Karl, you can flag the answer as correct, so that other users immediately spot that it solves the problem